# regex which finds keywords within c# setters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find out some specific setters in my c# code where i have some keywords within these setters.

First I needed to find out all setter in c#. I used this regex:

```
set\s*{[^{}]*(((?<Open>{)[^{}]*)+((?<Close-Open>})[^{}]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))}
```

It finds me all setters but now I want to refine the query with some keywords.

For example I have two setters:

```
public IDevice MainDevice
  {
   get { return _mainDevice; }
   set {
       if (_mainDevice == value)
       {
           return;
       }
        _mainDevice = value;
       }
   }


public IDevice SlaveDevice
{
 get { return _slaveDevice; }
 set
 {
    _slaveDevice = value;
    DoSomething();

    RaisePropertyChanged();
 }
}
```

Now I only want the setter with the keyword "RaisePropertyChanged".
How do I have to change the upper regex to achieve this?
I have tried a lot but it didn't work at all. I think I have a problem with the parenthesis level.

Comment: Get them all and then use `.Where(m => m.Contains("RaisePropertyChanged"))`. The regex can also be minimized to `set\s*{(?>[^{}]+|(?<O>{)|(?<-O>}))*(?(O)(?!))}`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you have access to the code, why not use Reflection after loading the assembly dynamically

Comment: Looks like a classic case of "now you have two problems". Unless you're restricted to a situation where you can't use anything else but a regex (or you will never do something like this again), consider analyzing C# with something specialized to analyze C#, like [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Comment: Jeroen is right. C# is not a regular language. If you want to parse C#, then *use a C# parser*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to have the regex parser work backwards (or [Right-to-Left Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#RightToLeft)) from `RaisePropertyChanged` back to `public`, not the standard direction, *left to right*, from `public` to `RaisePropertyChanged`.

*Otherwise the pattern consumes too much, does too much backtracking, finds other non related `public` items, such as class method, etc, and generally fails even on properties.*

**How**

By using the regex option `RightToLeft` we can create a base pattern which is based on the keyword[s] making the pattern easier to create as well as for the regex processor to run.

Below we also must use `Singleline` and also because the the pattern is commented we need `IgnorePatternWhitespace` as well.

```
public\s+                  # Public properties only
(?<Return>\w+)             # What is the return type
\s+                        # Space
(?<Name>\w+)               # Property Name
.+?                        # Bunch of text, minimal greed
RaisePropertyChanged       # Anchor to work back from.
```

We are able to access the property name and type returned because they are grouped by name into `myMatch.Groups["Return"].Value and`myMatch.Groups["Name"].Value`.

---

Here is the one result on the **data you provided**

**Group[0]:**

```
public IDevice SlaveDevice
{
  get { return _slaveDevice; }
  set
  {
     _slaveDevice = value;
     DoSomething();

     RaisePropertyChanged
```

**Groups[ ] After 0**

```
  ["Return"] → [1]:  IDevice
    ["Name"] → [2]:  SlaveDevice
```